# Windows 7 Service Pack 1 (SP1) final released to OEM, is it safe to install?

Tags: windows-7, service-pack

Softpedia has a copy of the W7 SP1 final release 32bit and 64bit for download, I checked the MD5 and SHA1 hashes and they match, do you think this is an unaltered version of OEM final release?

One could assume the hashes were made after any alteration.

http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-discussion/56605-windows-7-service-pack-1-sp1-download-available.html

http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Signatures-Updates/Windows-7-Service-Pack-1.shtml

Anyone know the reputation of Softpedia? I have downloaded many programs from them and they always come up clean, I store them in a folder for 2-3 weeks, then scan them again before install, paranoid I know.

Edit:

I downloaded the official release from Microsoft, the hashes matched that of Softpedia's download.

Comment: Sathya strikes again!

Comment: Edit, the download was a good one, see edit.

Comment: [-](http://superuser.com/q/235049/4377))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd wait for it to be released properly. Of course nothing is stopping you from doing a Restore Point, and if the MD5 hashes match, that's a pretty good sign. No bad things from Softpedia myself.

(Disclaimer: Softpedia distributes a couple of applications I've written.)

Comment: The SP will make a restore point by default, What apps have you written Randolph? Linky please.

Comment: Oooh, I don't know about that ... But since you asked, here's what's on Softpedia: http://www.softpedia.com/progMoreBy/Publisher-Intelligent-Technology-Solutions-36330.html